# Microsoft Graph: Delegate Login asks for "Consent on behalf of your organization"

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, appdelegate

I am using the msal `acquire_token_interactive()` method to login the user. I have `User.Read` and `Presence.Read` defined as scopes, both in the API permissions tab and in the `acquire_token_interactive` call.
However, when trying to login it displays "Consent on behalf of your organization", but the access shall only be for the individual user.

Microsoft Graph

Answer (score 0):

This MS official video finally gave me an explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80RdKeeDTss?t=1110 "Consent on behalf of your organization" is only visible when the Admin tries to login with this app, but not "normal" users of an organization.